# Creating ECS cluster with EFS mounting in separated VPCs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, subnet, amazon-efs

I'm trying to mount EFS file system to ECS container in task from different VPCs (for EFS and ECS cluster)/ Is it possible?

I'm getting the error

> ResourceInitializationError: failed to invoke EFS utils commands to set up EFS volumes: stderr: Failed to resolve "xxx.efs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com" - check that your file system ID is correct.

In [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/tutorial-efs-volumes.html#efs-security-group) tutorial the answer is no. But in this tutorial isn't used Peereng Connections.